# Connecting to a socket gives nothing

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io, retrofit

I use the library https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java
I do everything according to the documentation but nothing works.

```
private Socket mSocket;

{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket(URL);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mSocket.connect();
```

that's what is in `build.gradle(app)`

```
implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0'
```

can anyone explain what my problem is?

Comment: What does "nothing works" mean, do you get an error?

Comment: I found out that I need to go to the event and the channel, but I don’t know how to do it